# SelectedItem changing details which are then bound to previous selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

I have some hierachical data in the form of **regions** which contain **systems** which contain **entrances**
My WPF application has a list of **trips** which have an **entrance** as an attribute.  The UI is a split window with a ListControl and a 'details' control bound to the ListView.SelectedItem property as follows: (code edited for brevity, only relevant parts shown)

```xml
<local:ListView x:Name="listView"/>
<local:DetailsView DataContext="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

The details view consists of ComboBox for the attributes, amongst them:

```xml
<ComboBox Name="comboRegion" SelectionChanged="Region_Changed"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=main, Path=Regions, Mode=OneWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Region, Mode=OneWay}"/>
<ComboBox Name="comboSystem" SelectionChanged="System_Changed"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=main, Path=Systems, Mode=OneWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedItem="{Binding System, Mode=OneWay}"/>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=main, Path=Entrances, Mode=OneWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Enter}"/>
```

Trip.Enter is the attribute I want to edit, Trip.Region and Trip.System are read only and calculated from Trip.Enter.
main.Regions, main,systems and main.Entrances are lists local to the control which has the following code:

```cs
    public IEnumerable<Region> Regions { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<CaveSystem> Systems { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<Entrance> Entrances { get; private set; }

    private void Region_Changed(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Region = comboRegion.SelectedItem as Region;
        Systems = (region != null ? region.Systems : null);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Systems");
    }

    private void System_Changed(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ... Equivalent to Region_Changed except updates Entrances ...
    }
```

The Regions list is static so is populated once.
When a new region is selected, the Systems list is repopulated with the new list
When a new system is selected (also as a cascade from changing region), the entrances list is repopulated.

So far, so good.  This works as expected, selecting a trip in the list view binds its details to the combo boxes.  Changing the value in a combo box, updates the appropriate "lower level" boxes with the new list.
Finally, selecting an entrance updates the record itself (list view updates appropriately)

The problem is:
When I select a new record in the list view, the values in the new record appear in the combo boxes, but are also copied to the last record selected.

I think the problem is that, changing the data context for the details view causes the bindings to all be updated.  I think this happens in turn but changing the selected region causes a ripple effect in the lower level combo boxes which also change.  I think they are, at that point, still bound to the old record.

Can anyone suggest a way round this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found a solution!
I changed the bindings to

UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus

This means that the object is only updated if the user selects a new value in the combo box, Not when the combo box is updated due to changing the data context.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use strategy pattern. Dont change your datacontext, but chenge class in your datacontext. In this inner class you can have working logic but your datacontext will be same. Example:

```
public interface InnerDataContext
{
   public CaveSystem System{get;}
}

public class DataContext
{
   private InnerDataContext dc;

   public CaveSystem
   { get{ return dc.System; }}
}
```

you can change your inner datacontext when you want and it wouldnt throw update values.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm not sure if this will help but I found an answer myself - See below